# Navicat for Oracle executes query once then claims table does not exist

Tags: database, oracle, peoplesoft, navicat

I am trying to query a Oracle db that is supporting PeopleSoft. TOAD works fine, but Navicat will run any statement once then claim tables do not exist. I am on the evaluation version of Navicat. This happens for both basic and TNS connection types. The simple test below runs once then generates: [Err] ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    ps_stdnt_enrl
WHERE
    stdnt_enrl_status = 'E'
AND ROWNUM < 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting everything in upper case?  I know PS can be particular with its data dictionary's table names.

What about adding the connectid?  i.e. the PS table owner, typically SYSADM.  Does that help?  Could you be switching default schema after the first pass?

The other thing, and I know that is not really helpful, is that a PS database, typically with up to 10k tables, is a worse-case kinda thing with a lot of database utilities.  In normal custom-app databases, no one has 10K+ tables to look after.  When a db utility tries to have autocomplete, it can choke on those volumes.

Toad (on Mac OS) tends to flake out, probably because of that.  MS SQL's db admin utility has to have its autocomplete carefully turned off if you want to work with it realistically and even then you need to filter tablenames before bringing up any kind of system-wide table management dialogs.

Maybe there is something similar in Navicat you can turn off.